# How to shut down/stop databases that are running in mongodb without entering the mongodb shell

Tags: python, linux, database, mongodb, shell

I am not sure what I need to do. Every time I try to run the mongo shell on Linux I get an error asking me to stop the database before running MongoDB with start-noauth. I am not sure how to do that. Can you help me out?

I have tried to stop and exit MongoDB but the issue still exists.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want shutdown the "usually way":

```
systemctl stop mongod
or
service stop mongod
```

you can stop like this:

```
# enter in the mongodb
mongo
# change to admin database
use admin
# shutdown the database
db.shutdownServer()
```

Comment: Simple `mongo` (without credentials) will not work when authentication is enabled. You will get an `MongoServerError: command shutdown requires authentication` error.

Comment: watching the way he mentioned, i assume he is in a test environment, "new_user".

Answer (score 0):

In general it does not look very smart if you want to restart your MongoDB without authentication when authentication is actually enabled. Usually there is a reason to have authentication enabled.

The proper way would be to stop the MongoDB

```
systemctl stop mongod
```

and then disable authentication in your configuration file, typically at `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

Then you can restart the service with

```
systemctl start mongod
```

If you don't know the location of the config file, check the service file:

```
$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-16 14:29:12 CET; 1 months 15 days ago


$ cat /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
...
```

Above commands apply for Redhat/CentOS Linux, they may differ on your Linux.

But as said, usually it is a good habit to enable authentication and I would assume there was a reason to enable it.